# Check The Visibility of Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working on Android app project and trying detect the visibility of Navigation Bar (the on-screen one) when onCreate() in order to determine the screen height, `mScreenHeight`. In short,the idea is how to check if the navbar is visible on the screen or not.
So far, I went with this code:

```
Point screenFull = new Point() , screenNavBar = new Point();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(screenFull);
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenNavBar);

View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
if ((decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0 ) {
    mScreenHeight = screenNavBar.y;
} else {
    mScreenHeight = screenFull.y;
}
```

But everytime the app runs, it always gave the result of the screen height as like the navbar is visible, evethough I already hid the navbar. I already surfed the internet, didn't find any close answer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If by "already hid the navbar", you mean that you set immersive mode on previously in onCreate(), then I think you may just need to perform your check later, after the activity has had a chance to activate the mode. Try moving your check into onResume(), if that doesn't work try checking after a few more seconds.

I've found the immersive mode setting to be very difficult to work with depending on what API levels your supporting, and especially if your building to Amazon as well.